# numpy getting row indices in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm sorry in advance if this question is not worded well, as I'm not sure how to describe what I am doing concisely.

I have a multidimensional numpy array where the higher dimensions are a unique identifier and the lower dimensions are unique results.  In the typical case each result is a vector, but the result itself can also be higher dimensional.  I want to be able to retrieve unique indices that will return each result.  the reason I need the indices is that I need to be able to look up a result and then join it alongside some other data that is different resolution.  So I need to be able to iterate through each value and then add the additional information and return the combined result.  Note that I eventually need to be able to filter these unique measurements according to some user defined function (along the lines of np.argwhere).  For now I just want to tackle the simple problem of getting all the rows.  Here is a simple example where I have reduced the dimensions.

In this example each row represents a measurement result. So there are 6 results and each result is a 2 element vector:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(6,2)
```

What I want is a list of indices to access each row.  So I'd want some code that can generate the list below:

```
row_indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

then I can easily access each row as:

```
for row_idx in row_indices:
    row = a[row_idx]
```

Note that I don't want a hardcoded method to get the row indexes for a 2d matrix.  My index is atleast 3 dimensional so I need a generalized solution.

Comment: ... you can just use `for row in a: print(row)` if you want to iterate over the rows. But if you *must* use indices for some reason, for any axis `i`, you can get a list of possible indices using `range(a.shape[i])`, so for rows, `range(a.shape[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another question that I just answered I worked with

```
In [11]: my_array = np.array(range(81)).reshape((3,3,3,3))
```

Your description isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like you want to iterate on several of those dimensions.

One way to do this is with the help of `ndindex`:

```
In [16]: list(np.ndindex(3,3))
Out[16]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
In [17]: for idx in np.ndindex(3,3):
    ...:     print(my_array[idx])
    ...:     
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
[[ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]
 [15 16 17]]
[[18 19 20]
...
 [78 79 80]]
```

I could do the same iteration with reshaping:

```
In [18]: arr1 = my_array.reshape(9,3,3)
In [19]: for a in arr1:
    ...:     print(a)
    ...:     
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
[[ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]
 [15 16 17]]
[[18 19 20]
 [21 22 23]
 [24 25 26]]
...
```

or with `for i in range(9): arr1[i] ...`

Comment: Thanks, this does the job for the nominal case.  Is there a way to filter these higher dimensioned indices in some way like with argwhere?  Lets say some of these dimensions contain np.nan and i want to remove these.  I know i can combine np.isnan with argwhere, but this gives  me the full dimensions.

Comment: I think you need to ask this in a new question, with example.